# Basic Encryption in C++

Tags: arrays, math, encryption

I'm supposed to write a program for an affine cipher that that accepts an input of two keys, a and b, checks if they are prime, and applies them to the formula [y=(a*x + b) mod26] where x is the character to be encrypted and y is the encrypted character, and if valid values were provided, use these values to encrypt the string the user gave you and output the result.  My problem is that after checking for the keys the program just idles and doesn't progress and I dont know what to do.  It asks for the two keys and checks if they are prime but after checking the second key the program doesn't do anything, including exit.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>

using namespace std;
const int S = 11;
array<char, 52> LETTERS = { 'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z',
'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z' };
array<char, 52> ENCRYPT;

string String() 
{
    char Array[S];
    string hellocipher;
    const string MESSAGE = "Please Enter Text Up To 11 Characters: ";

    do 
    {
        if(hellocipher.size() == 0)
            cout << MESSAGE << endl;
        else if(hellocipher.size() > S)
        {
            cout << "Wrong Amount Char" << endl;
            cout << MESSAGE << endl;
        }
        cin >> hellocipher;
    } while (hellocipher.size() == 0 || hellocipher.size() > S);

    return hellocipher;
}

bool IsPrime(int intNumber) 
{
    int i = 2;
    for (; i <= intNumber; i++)
    {
        if (intNumber % i == 0) 
            break;
    }
    return i == intNumber;
}

int GetKey() 
{
    int a = 0;
    const string MESSAGE = "Please Enter A Key value. Value must be prime number between 1 and 101 : ";
    do
    {
        if(a==0)
            cout << MESSAGE << endl;
        else 
        {
            cout << "This key value is not prime.\n";
            cout << MESSAGE << endl;
        }
        cin >> a;
    } while (a == 0 || !IsPrime(a)); 

    return a;
}

char Encrypt(char ch, int a, int b) 
{
    return (char)((((((int)ch)*a) + b) % 26)+65);
}

array<char, 52> EncArr(array<char, 52> arr,int A, int B) 
{
    //int size = arr.size;
    array<char, 52> arrReturn;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
    {
        arrReturn[i]=Encrypt(arr[i],A,B);
    }
    return arrReturn;
}

string  Process(string strEncrpt, array<char, 52> arrMapNonEnc, array<char, 52> arrMapEnc) 
{
    string strReturn="";

    for (int i = 0; i < strEncrpt.length(); i++)
    {
        for (int inx = 0; inx < 51; inx++)
        {
            if (arrMapNonEnc[inx] == strEncrpt[i]) 
            {
                strReturn.append(string(1, arrMapEnc[inx]));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return strReturn;
}

void PrintToScreen(string str ) 
{
    cout << str << endl;
}

int main()
{
    //Step 1: Get String for encription
    string nonencryptedcipher = String();
    //Step 2: Get Key 1 number
    int a = GetKey();
    //Step 3: Get Key 2 number
    int b = GetKey();

    array<char, 52> EncArr(array < char, 52 > arr, int a, int b);  //replace char with LETTERS
    //Step 4: Encript string
    string strEncpt = Process(nonencryptedcipher, LETTERS, ENCRYPT);
    //Step 5: Present on screen
    PrintToScreen(strEncpt);

    system("pause>null");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: unrelated, but this "cipher" has a major problem if a is 2 or 13, since several different input characters are then mapped to the same output character.

Comment: ["Schneier's Law"](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html): Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break.

Comment: Wondering why you are creating yet-another-encryption-scheme?

Comment: For why the program doesn't do anything, use a debugger to set traps and trace execution, or even *caveman debugging*: add print statements.